# Keycloak client vs user

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I understand that keycloak has built-in clients and we add the users later on.

But in general, **what is the difference between a client and a user in Keycloak?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In short words, not only for keycloak but for OAuth and OpenId Connect too, a client represents a resource which some users can access. The built-in clients for keycloak represent some resources for keycloak itself.

Comment: So can we say if an app has that allows sign-in-via-google is a client and google itself as server ?

Can we say each realm is for a new client ? And KeyCloak itself is a OAuth server ?

Comment: 1. Google would be the identity provider. 2. It depends on how the idp treats the client. 3. Keycloak is an identity provider, it supports openid connect (which is oauth based) and saml authorization protocols.

Comment: @arpit, please, ask a separate question.

Comment: Isn't client a third party application which wants to access a certain resource on behalf of a user(resource owner) once the authorization is provided?

Answer (score 22):

According to the Keycloak documentation

1. User - Users are entities that are able to log into your system
2. Client - Clients are entities that can request Keycloak to authenticate a user. Most 
   often, clients are applications and services that want to use Keycloak to secure 
   themselves and provide a single sign-on solution. Clients can also be entities that 
   just want to request identity information or an access token so that they can 
   securely invoke other services on the network that are secured by Keycloak

Answer (score 8):

Clients and users are two completely different constructs in keycloak.

In plain English, client is an application. Example for an application could be a e.g. yelp.com or any mobile application. Client can be a simple REST API. Keycloak's built in clients are for keycloak internal use, But any user-defined application has to be registered as a client in keycloak.

Users are the one which authenticate via keycloak to gain access to these applications/clients. Users are stored in keycloak DB or any externally hosted LDAP but synced with keycloak.